# How can I disable Spaces in Lion?

Tags: macos, spaces

I used to use spaces a lot on Leopard and Snow Leopard, but the way it works on Lion is annoying for me, especially when it sends the full screen apps to a Space at the end of the row.

Is there a way to disable Spaces altogether on Lion?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the question. Isn't having just one space then the solution?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want. But unlike snow leopard, there is no "spaces" in the preferences, or I am missing something here!

Comment: You say that you hate how full screen apps are put all the way to the right, well as of 10.7.2, you can rearrange the order of spaces so that full screen apps can be directly to the right of the main space

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Enter Mission Control
2. Hover over the selected space or hold <kbd>⌥</kbd>
3. remove by clicking on the x

[image]

Comment: That's what I needed! Thank you. I inherited 9 spaces from my Snow leopard and while I was used to the 3x3 spatial arrangement of my 9 spaces in SL having 9 spaces in a row and a bunch of fullscreen apps at the end was very annoying. Now I get ride of them.

Comment: Yeah, I really hate Mission Control (apart from the full screen feature). Having 4+ Spaces ordered in 1D is quite annoying. You end up swiping more than you should. And Exposé? Mission Control does not fully integrate Exposé. You can mainly use is to switch between Spaces or Apps - but not windows. However, we already had a feature to switch between apps: Alt+Tab

Comment: and why they removed the sweep with four fingers = Command-Tab, I used to use that all the time!

Comment: @Matt for what it's worth, you can do a three- (or four-, depending on the Mission Control multitouch setting) finger swipe downwards to perform Expose on the windows of the active application.

Comment: As of "Mavericks" -  aka 10.9.. you can also "ADD a desktop" from `Mission Control`.  Look for the blueish, plus-symbol-ly button on the top right side of the screen.

Answer (score 4):

The function "Spaces" doesn't exist any more.

This new Feature is called "Mission Control" in OS X Lion, and it's including the old Feature Spaces.

You cannot deactivate Mission Control, because it's an implemented way to handle FullScreen-Apps.

You have to live with that, but it can bee very helpful after a few days!